# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket (error 2002)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

i get one error when i try to connect to Mysql server with

```
mysql -u root -p
```

error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (111)
```

yesterday it worked without any problems

Comment: Have you confirmed that MySQL is running?

Comment: @matigo , yes mysql  is running